# Unable to get data from Retrofit when used in for loop

Tags: java, android, api, retrofit

I'm using MVVM and I'm trying to loop over a list of integers that has some IDs for movies genres, I'm using retrofit and I have a function that should return a list of movies based on the id, but it's working for some reason.

I tried to pass the id to the function and it worked, however when I tried to loop over a list of ids to  get different results and put them in a RecyclerView it didn't work

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView mMainRecycler;
    MoviesViewModel moviesViewModel;
    MainRecyclerAdapter mainRecyclerAdapter;


    Context context = this;

    List<String> genresNames = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> genresIds = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Movies.Result> listResults = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mMainRecycler = findViewById(R.id.main_recycler);
        mMainRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));



        moviesViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(MoviesViewModel.class);

        moviesViewModel.getMoviesGenres();
        moviesViewModel.mutableMoviesGenres.observe(this, new Observer<List<MoviesGenres.GenresBean>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MoviesGenres.GenresBean> genresBeans) {

                for (int i = 0; i < genresBeans.size(); i++) {
                    genresIds.add(genresBeans.get(i).getId());
                    genresNames.add(genresBeans.get(i).getName());
                }
                mainRecyclerAdapter.addNames(genresNames);
            }
        });


        for(int i = 0; i < genresIds.size(); i++) {
            moviesViewModel.getMovieWithGenre(genresIds.get(i));
        }


        moviesViewModel.mutableMoviesWithGenre.observe(this, new Observer<List<Movies.Result>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Movies.Result> results) {
                listResults.addAll(results);
                mainRecyclerAdapter.addResults(listResults);
            }
        });

        mMainRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        mainRecyclerAdapter = new MainRecyclerAdapter(context, genresNames, listResults);
        mMainRecycler.setAdapter(mainRecyclerAdapter);
    }


}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MoviesViewModel extends ViewModel {

    public MutableLiveData<List<Movies.Result>> mutablePopularMovies = new MutableLiveData<>();

    public void getPopular(){

        MoviesClient.getInstance().getPopular().enqueue(new Callback<Movies>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Movies> call, @NonNull Response<Movies> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    mutablePopularMovies.setValue(response.body().getResults());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Movies> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });


    }
    public MutableLiveData<List<Movies.Result>> mutableMoviesWithGenre = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public void getMovieWithGenre(int i){
        MoviesClient.getInstance().getMoviesWithGenre(i).enqueue(new Callback<Movies>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<Movies> call, @NonNull Response<Movies> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    mutableMoviesWithGenre.setValue(response.body().getResults());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<Movies> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

    public MutableLiveData<List<MoviesGenres.GenresBean>> mutableMoviesGenres = new MutableLiveData<>();
    public void getMoviesGenres() {
        MoviesClient.getInstance().getMoviesByGenre().enqueue(new Callback<MoviesGenres>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<MoviesGenres> call, @NonNull Response<MoviesGenres> response) {
                if(response.isSuccessful() && response.body() != null) {
                    mutableMoviesGenres.setValue(response.body().getGenres());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<MoviesGenres> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

MainRecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public class MainRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MainRecyclerAdapter.MainViewHolder> {

    private Context mContext;
    private List<Movies.Result> moviesResults;
    private List<String> moviesNames;

    public MainRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<String> moviesNames, List<Movies.Result> moviesResults) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.moviesNames = moviesNames;
        this.moviesResults = moviesResults;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MainRecyclerAdapter.MainViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MainViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.category_rv_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MainRecyclerAdapter.MainViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.genresTv.setText(moviesNames.get(position));
        setCatItemRecycler(holder.mRecycler, moviesResults);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesNames.size();
    }

    public void addNames(List<String> moviesGenres) {
        moviesNames.addAll(moviesGenres);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addResults(List<Movies.Result> listResults) {
        moviesResults.addAll(listResults);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public class MainViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView genresTv;
        RecyclerView mRecycler;


        public MainViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            genresTv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cat_title);
            mRecycler = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler);

        }
    }

    private void setCatItemRecycler(RecyclerView recyclerView, List<Movies.Result> moviesResults){

        MovieAdapter movieAdapter = new MovieAdapter(mContext, moviesResults);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mContext, RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL, false));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(movieAdapter);
    }

}
```

Chile (inner) RecyclerView:

```
public class MovieAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder> {


    private List<Movies.Result> moviesResult;
    private Context mContext;

    public MovieAdapter(Context context, List<Movies.Result> moviesResult) {
        this.moviesResult = moviesResult;
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new MovieViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.movie_item, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MovieAdapter.MovieViewHolder holder, int position) {
        String imageUrl = MoviesClient.IMAGE_URL + moviesResult.get(position).getPosterPath();
        Glide.with(holder.mPosterImage.getContext()).load(imageUrl).into(holder.mPosterImage);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesResult.size();
    }


    public class MovieViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        ImageView mPosterImage;
        public MovieViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mPosterImage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.poster_image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get error or output isn't what you want?

Comment: output isn't what I want, I edited the post and added a comment down to describe the problem better

Answer (score 0):

first of all you didn't share the ViewModel class, I thing you may have a problem with the observers, because your listResults will only be updated after the Retrofit returns the result, so when you call mMainRecycler.setAdapter(mainRecyclerAdapter) you are doing it with your empty list.

Another thing that may be causing this is because your data does not know it has returned, so when you use listResults.addAll(results), make sure that inside the adapter you call .notifyDataSetChanged()

A function like this should do the trick (inside the adapter):

```
public void updateGenres(List<Genres> genres){
    listResults.addAll(genres);
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: sorry for that mistake, I edited the post and added the ViewModel class, I'm trying to implement a nested RecyclerView the parent recycler should show genres names and the horizontal recyclers that has a list of movies based on the genres. however, I only get the names and inner RecyclerViews show nothing. when I tried to pass only one id instead of looping over a list of different ids (like in the second loop in main activity) everything worked fine, but of course all the inner RecyclerView showed the same list so i wanted to use a loop and pass different Ids.